# log4net could not generate any log file

Tags: .net

I have a VB.NET 3.5 windows service which is going to use the log4net, however, I was wondering if there is any error setting in my code because I cannot get any log from log4net,

VB CODE

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports log4net
Imports log4net.Config

Public Class Service1
    Private Shared ReadOnly log As ILog = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType(Service1))
    Dim cnt As Integer = 0

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.

        'log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath)
        'BasicConfigurator.Configure()
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(New System.IO.FileInfo(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\log4netsetup.xml"))
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\www.txt", "WTF")

        log.Debug("DEBUG: Service Started.")
        log.Info("INFO: Service Started.")

        Dim timer As New Timer(New TimerCallback(AddressOf downloadPrintJob), Nothing, 1000, 50000)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    End Sub

    Private Sub downloadPrintJob(ByVal o As Object)
        cnt += 1
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("c:\temp\print_service\aaa.txt", cnt)
        log.Debug("this is the log message")
    End Sub
End Class
```

log4netsetup.xml

```
<log4net>
    <!-- A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender -->
    <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">

        <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1 -->
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="A1" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

The www.txt and aaa.txt can be both generated and write the text inside them, so I think this is not an issue related to permission. Please advice, thank you.

**UPDATED:**

Thanks Astef, I have moved the XMLConfigurator to the Service1.Designer.vb, but it seems not working still.

```
' The main entry point for the process
<MTAThread()> _
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Shared Sub Main()
    Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

    ' More than one NT Service may run within the same process. To add
    ' another service to this process, change the following line to
    ' create a second service object. For example,
    '
    '   ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase () {New Service1, New MySecondUserService}
    '
    XmlConfigurator.Configure(New System.IO.FileInfo(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\log4netsetup.xml"))
    ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New Service1}

    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must configure log4net before any logger was instantiated.

Here is your instantiation (in `Service1` static field):

```
Private Shared ReadOnly log As ILog = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType(Service1))
```

And here is configuration (in `Service1.OnStart` method):

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(New System.IO.FileInfo(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\log4netsetup.xml"))
```

I'm not VB guy, but I think that static field initializer runs before any other code in methods, and that's must be the problem.

Try to instantiate a logger in a method right after configuration.